# Pagination url issues with express js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, dom

I've created a Pagination and i'm facing some issues, the goal is to when the URL is '/platform' then use the DOM to update the pagination. I'm using Express to pass in the URL path (req.url).

```js
var mainPath = '<%=url[1]%>'
var pathURL = '<%=url[2]%>'
var pathnum = '<%=url[3]%>'
let link1 = document.getElementById('link1')
let link2 = document.getElementById('link2')
let link3 = document.getElementById('link3')
let pastPage = pathnum - 1;
let nextPage = pathnum + 1;
if(mainPath == 'page') {
 link1.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/page/'+ pastPage +'">'+ pastPage +'</a>'
 link2.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/page/'+ pathnum +'">'+ pathnum +'</a>'
 link3.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/page/'+ nextPage +'">'+ nextPage +'</a>'
} else if(mainPath == 'platform') {
 link1.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/platform/'+pathnum+'/'+pastPage+'">'+pastPage+'</a>'
 link2.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/platform/'+pathnum+'/'+pathnum+'">'+pathnum+'</a>'
 link3.innerHTML = '<a class="page-link" href="/platform/'+pathnum+'/'+pathNum+'">'+nextPage+'</a>'
}
```

The issue is, when the URL is 'platform', it doesn't update the href to like below

```
href='/platform'
```

Comment: Check variable naming... `link` and `linkk`,both are different.

Comment: fixed typo errors, but it still doesn't do what i need it todo.

Comment: I hope you are running this code in Browser, can you please add console.log output for each variable in to your question?

Comment: Im using alerts.